# How to change the color of the text in each color bar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[xylophone pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFcWS.png)

The last thing I would like to change on this app is the color of the text to make it blend better with the background color of each bar.

For example, I would like to change the 'Red' text to yellow. I would like to change the 'Light blue' text to orange.

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(XylophoneApp());

class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  void buttonSound(int noteNumber) {
    final player = AudioCache();
    player.play('note$noteNumber.wav');
  }

  Expanded buildKey(
      {Color color, int noteNumber, String text}) {
    return Expanded(
      child: FlatButton(
        color: color,
        onPressed: () {
          buttonSound(noteNumber);
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Vast Shadow',
              fontSize: 20,
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              letterSpacing: 2,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              buildKey(color: Colors.red, noteNumber: 1, text: 'Red'),
              buildKey(color: Colors.blue, noteNumber: 2, text: 'Light Blue'),
              buildKey(color: Colors.orangeAccent, noteNumber: 3, text: 'Orange Accent'),
              buildKey(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent, noteNumber: 4, text: 'Purple'),
              buildKey(color: Colors.lightGreen, noteNumber: 5, text: 'Key Lime'),
              buildKey(color: Colors.blueGrey, noteNumber: 6, text: 'Blue Grey'),
              buildKey(color: Colors.lime, noteNumber: 7, text: 'Yellow Accent'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just add another parameter to the `buildKey` for the text color and set the `color` in the`TextStyle` to this parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another parameter for the text color

```
      {Color color, int noteNumber, String text, Color textColor}) {
    return Expanded(
      child: FlatButton(
        color: color,
        onPressed: () {
          buttonSound(noteNumber);
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Vast Shadow',
              fontSize: 20,
              color: textColor,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              letterSpacing: 2,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Then call the method passing the text color

```
buildKey(color: Colors.red, noteNumber: 1, text: 'Red', textColor: Colors.yellow)
```

Make sure you pass the textColor.

Comment: apparently I have a reputation score of less than 15 so I clicked the check mark but the up vote isn't allowing it to be publicly available.